# Можно в qml передать QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Я нашёл как передавать из qt в qml QAbstractListModel. Но не нашёл как передать QMap. Возможно передавать в qml QMap,QVector и QList?
Пример 1 передачи данных из из qt в qml [тут](http://easy-qt.blogspot.com/2012/02/qt-qml.html) и второй вариант [тут](http://easy-qt.blogspot.com/2012/02/qt-qml-2.html) .

threedobjectmodel.h

```
#ifndef THREEDOBJECTMODEL_H
#define THREEDOBJECTMODEL_H

class ThreeDModel;

#include <QString>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QList>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QModelIndex>

class ThreeDObjectModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreeDObjectModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    enum ThreeDModelRolse {
        mapOBVPRole = Qt::DisplayRole,
//        mapTextureRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
//        mapStateRole = Qt::UserRole + 2
    };
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const; // функция доступа к данным
//    QMap<int, QVariant> itemData(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QMap<int, QString> setItemOBVP(const QModelIndex &index, const QMap<int, QString> &roles);
    bool setItemDataTexture(const QModelIndex &index, const QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> &roles);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const; // количество элементов в модели
public slots:
    void addThreeDModel(ThreeDModel ct);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<ThreeDModel> ThreeDModels;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles; // роли
};

class ThreeDModel
{
public:
    ThreeDModel(QMap<int,QString> _mapOBVP, QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> _mapTexture, QMap<int,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>> _mapState)
    {
//        name = _name;
//        url = _url;
//        nameRUS = _nameRUS;
        mapOBVP = _mapOBVP;
        mapTexture = _mapTexture;
        mapState = _mapState;
    }

//    void setName (QString _name)
//    {
//        name = _name;
//    }

//    void setUrl (QString _url)
//    {
//        url = _url;
//    }

//    void setNameRUS (QString _nameRUS)
//    {
//        nameRUS = _nameRUS;
//    }

    void setMapOBVP (QMap<int,QString> _mapOBVP)
    {
        mapOBVP = _mapOBVP;
    }

    void setMapTexture (QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> _mapTexture)
    {
        mapTexture = _mapTexture;
    }

    void setMapState (QMap<int,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>> _mapState)
    {
        mapState = _mapState;
    }

//    QString getName() const
//    {
//        return name;
//    }

//    QString getUrl() const
//    {
//        return url;
//    }

//    QString getNameRUS() const
//    {
//        return nameRUS;
//    }

    QMap<int,QString> getMapOBVP() const
    {
        return mapOBVP;
    }

    QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> getMapTexture() const
    {
        return mapTexture;
    }

    QMap<int,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>> getMapState() const
    {
        return mapState;
    }

private:
    QMap<int,QString> mapOBVP;
    QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> mapTexture;
    QMap<int,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>> mapState;
};

#endif // THREEDOBJECTMODEL_H
```

threedobjectmodel.cpp

```
#include "threedobjectmodel.h"

ThreeDObjectModel::ThreeDObjectModel(QObject *parent):
    QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    roles[mapOBVPRole] = "obvp";
    roles[mapTextureRole] = "texture";
    roles[mapStateRole] = "state";

}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ThreeDObjectModel::roleNames() const
{
    return roles;
}

QMap<int, QString> ThreeDObjectModel::setItemOBVP(const QModelIndex &index, const QMap<int, QString> &roles)
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > ThreeDModels.count())
    {
        if (index.row()==1)
        {
            return QMap<int, QString>();
        }
    }
    const ThreeDModel & ct = ThreeDModels[1];
    if (roles == mapOBVPRole)
        return ct.getMapOBVP();
    return QMap<int, QString>();
}

bool ThreeDObjectModel::setItemDataTexture(const QModelIndex &index, const QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>> &roles)
{
 return true;
}



QVariant ThreeDObjectModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > ThreeDModels.count())
    {
        if (index.row()==0)
        {
            return QVariant();
        }
    }
//        return QVariant();
    const ThreeDModel & ct = ThreeDModels[index.row()];
//    if (role == mapOBVPRole)
//        return ct.getMapOBVP();
//    else if (role == UrlRole)
//        return ct.getUrl();
//    else if (role == NameRUSRole)
//        return ct.getNameRUS();
    return QVariant();
}



void ThreeDObjectModel::addThreeDModel(ThreeDModel ct)
{
    ThreeDModels << ct;
}

int ThreeDObjectModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return ThreeDModels.size();
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
    ThreeDObjectModel model;
    QMap<int,QString> getMapOBVP;
    getMapOBVP.insert("1","test");
    model.setItemOBVP(getMapOBVP);
    view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &getMapOBVP);
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415767/how-to-expose-qmap-to-qml-using-qdeclarative

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Не наглядный пример. я не совсем понимаю его

Comment: Какой у вас QMap?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Я сейчас распишу в вопросе

Comment: @Alexander Chernin QMap<int,QString>,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>,QMap<int,QMap<int,QMap<QString,QString>>>

Comment: Что и как тут передается из/в qml?

Comment: тут создаётся экземпляр ThreeDObjectModel  класса и передаётся с помощью view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91910/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-ivan-triumphov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QVariantMap` это синоним `QMap<QString, QVariant>` (typedef). Таким образом, вам надо ключи перевести в QString, а их значения в QVariant и дальше как обычно.

Qml работает с QVariantMap и с QVariantList как с обычными/классическими JavaScript объектами.

Пример:

```
class MapDataSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void mapChanged(const QVariantMap& data);
}

//...
```

main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<MapDataSender>(...);
```

*.qml:

```
Window
{
    MapDataSender {
        onMapChanged:
        {
            // Нам доступен аргумент с именем data
            // Выводим его свойства и их значения
            for (var prop in data) {
                console.log(prop, "=", data[prop])
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал сделать вашим способом но у меня в консоле :module "Sender.MapDataSenderTexture" version 0.1 is not installed

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Вы какой-то класс не зарегистрировали в qml

Comment: qmlRegisterType<MapDataSenderTexture>("Sender.MapDataSenderTexture", 1, 0, "MapDST");  Так же регистрировать ?   QObject надо регистрировать ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965801/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A1-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-qml-module-version-0-1-is-not-installed

Comment: Я убирал  Sender, всё равно  is not installed

Comment: А как связать сигнал mapChanged с qml .... я сейчас его испускаю но в консоле не вы водиться console.log(prop, "=", data[prop])?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov как у меня в ответе, а в С++ классе не забудьте его эмитировать

Comment: @IvanTriumphov еще обратите внимание, что имена сигнала с++ и приемника  qml отличаются префиксом `on` за которым имя сигнала идет с большой буквы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92035/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-alexander-chernin).