# Как регистрировать С++ классы для QML? module "" version 0.1 is not installed

Tags: c++, классы, qml

Я делаю по [уроку](https://habr.com/ru/post/140899/) . Но у меня ошибка `:qrc:/Samples/Analysis/ViewshedGeoElement/ViewshedGeoElement.qml:29:1: module "MapDataSenderTexture" version 0.1 is not installed`
Мой код:

mapdatasendertexture.h

```
#ifndef MAPDATASENDERTEXTURE_H
#define MAPDATASENDERTEXTURE_H

#include <QObject>
//#include "threedmodeltexture.h"

class MapDataSenderTexture: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int someProperty READ getSomeProperty WRITE setSomeProperty NOTIFY mapChanged)
public:
    explicit MapDataSenderTexture(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int getSomeProperty()const;
    void setSomeProperty(const int &);
signals:
    void mapChanged(const int &);
private:
    int someProperty;
};

#endif // MAPDATASENDERTEXTURE_H
```

mapdatasendertexture.cpp

```
#include "mapdatasendertexture.h"

MapDataSenderTexture::MapDataSenderTexture(QObject *parent)
{

}

int MapDataSenderTexture::getSomeProperty()const
{
//    qDebug() << "I'm getter";
    return someProperty;
}

void MapDataSenderTexture::setSomeProperty(const int &i)
{
//    qDebug() << "I'm setter";
    someProperty = i;
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
    qmlRegisterType<MapDataSenderTexture>("MapDataSenderTexture", 1, 0, "MapDST");
...
```

ViewshedGeoElement.qml

```
...
import MapDataSenderTexture 0.1
...
...
    MapDST {
        onMapChanged:
        {
...
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это неверно по смыслу:

```
qmlRegisterType<MapDataSenderTexture>("MapDataSenderTexture", 1, 0, "MapDST");
```

Первый параметр это путь к виртуальному пакету (выберите любой).

Например так:

```
qmlRegisterType<MapDataSenderTexture>("my.widgets", 1, 0, "MapDST");
```

Применение в qml:

```
import my.widgets 1.0

//...
    MapDST {
    }
//...
```

Comment: Всё равно qml:29:1: module "my.widgets" version 0.1 is not installed

Comment: у меня указана версия 1.0 и у вас 1.0

Comment: Гениально ...версию не правильно указал ....спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @IvanTriumphov пожалуйста. Тут тоже можете галочку поставить )

Comment: Я поставлю когда это будет раз решено ...сейчас не могу поставить ....надо подождать

Answer (score 3):

Иногда, вместо регистрации модуля, я пробрасываю глобальную переменную непосредственно в QML

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>

#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView viewer;
    viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    BackEnd backend;

    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backEnd", &backend);

    QObject::connect(viewer.engine(), &QQmlEngine::quit, &viewer, &QWindow::close);
    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    viewer.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

backend.h

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
BackEnd();

signals:

public slots:
QString getContacts();
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

ColumnLayout{
    function lol(){
    xmlModel.xml=backEnd.getContacts();
    }
```

Это позволяет не разбираться со странной системой модулей QML и использовать сущности из C++ повторно, не плодя лишний код

Comment: Спасибо буду знать

Comment: Мне надо работать с QMap<int, ThreeDModelTexture*> mapTexture; Как его можно обработать в qml ?

Comment: Если можно пример ....как работать с QMap в qml